# Use Unique in a Filter formula

Tags: google-sheets, filter, unique, google-sheets-formula

I have a list of identifiers and a value for each identifier which is filled automatically.
I want to **filter** **the list** so I will only get unique identifiers and their respective value.
e.g. "Dana" can appears 3 times but in the filtered table I only want to see the name (and the value) once.
Ideally I'd like to use something like
`=filter(a:b,unique(a:a)` which obviously doesn't work.

As mentioned, the list updates automatically so a formula that needs to be dragged won't do the trick.

Note: It can be solved by extracting uniques from col A

```
=unique(A:A)
```

and then an Arrayformula + vLookup

```
=arrayformula(if(I1:I>0,vlookup(I1:I,A:B,2,0),""))
```

but I'm curious to see if it can be solved using Filter for more elegance.

Here's an example (including the solution I mentioned):
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1heKdV3U6mdGYkHCIWkeUyqo6AfhgV7ItSmolibH7ecU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Which value do you want the first or a sum?

Comment: In the same order of the original table. Name first, value second. thanks

Comment: Can you add your expected outcome?

Comment: Please look in the spreadheet, the original table is in col A:B, in I:J is the expected result (using the vlookup solution I mentioned). I want the I:J result using a Filter (if possible).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use the following

```
=UNIQUE(A:B)
```

[image]

---

**UPDATE**

Following OP's [comment/request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64925432/use-unique-in-a-filter-formula#comment114794475_64926185):

> Nice fix! Out of curiosity - is it possible to still use it with the filter function (for example, if I wanted to filter by Col B or add other restrictions) ?

Sure. Try these ones out

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(A:B,B:B=333))
```

OR

```
=FILTER(UNIQUE(A:B),UNIQUE(B:B)=333)
```

---

**Reference:**

- [`UNIQUE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093198?hl=en)

Comment: Nice fix! Out of curiosity - is it possible to still use it with the filter function (for example, if I wanted to filter by Col B or add other restrictions) ?
In any case, thanks. Great solution.

Comment: Hi, I accepted the answer, thanks again. Please note that the 2 ways to filter by Column B do not work. I've added them in the spreadsheet (col I and col L). If you can look into that as well it would be great.

Comment: They do work. I had a mistake in the formulas. Instead of `B:B` I used `A:A`. They are now fixed. Thank you for taking the time to accept.